# Spring Security: Pushing username into model

Tags: model, controller, spring-security, interceptor, taglib

This is basically a question about style or best practice. I want to know the best way to pass the username to the model variables accessible by my views. Without writing this part of the logic for every controller. There are basically three ways to do this:

1. Using the spring security taglibs: 
   http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

   Down-side: "some people prefer to keep as little logic as possible in the view". I agree. Any objections?
2. Implementing an InterceptorHandler: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-introduction

   The best practice to get the user name here is probably SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(). After that the user name needs to be set by calling httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("userName",userName);

   This seems awkward. Somehow. Is it (**question**)? Another problem is the fact that one has to start doing handler mappings by hand again as in before Spring 2.5 to be able to use interceptors for single controllers. **Question:** is his a bad thing?
3. Using the principal parameter and implementing an abstract controller, i.e. using the @ModelAttribute(...) annotation (don't know another method from the top of my head)

   So the **question** is what is the NICE way to push the user name into the model?

The purpose of this question is to clarify my understanding of the Spring security concepts and to learn about best practices, which is important when starting new projects, I think.

Comment: Isn't username already included in the Principal after authentication?

Comment: It is. I don't know where it comes from, but it is (emperically). Your point being?